# EventtoCommand / SL5 / MVVMLight V3

Tags: mvvm-light

I'm using V3 and recently decided to try SL5 against my Silverlight project.  I've upgraded Blend to the V5 version, un-installed V4 SL and installed V5 tools.  Updated all the references that I could find.  The Event to command behaviour still remains unrecognized.

I've searched the web and have found no mention of V3 EventToCommand and SL5.

Any suggestions/experience with this?  With Telerik have issues with SL5 RC as well, am I simply too early?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you referenced the `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` as well? EventToCommand is a Blend behavior and the base code for those is in that DLL. That assembly comes with MVVM Light but originally belongs to the Expression Blend SDK for SL4. I tried to search for Blend SDK for SL5 but didn't find any (or then it's just in the SL5 Beta SDK). Maybe that could be related.. what's the error message that you get?

Comment: We installed the Blen Expression for SL5, which I think also updated this dll.  We had to back out of the SL5 RC install, go through a painful registry clean, and then reinstall SL4.  That seemed to get everything working again.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the MVVM Light v.4 and the EventToCommad will work in SL5.
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/